# Python: Compare first line of files and save their path

Tags: python

I'm trying to get my script to read the first line of each file on the parent folder looking for a flag, so It knows how to process them later. This code does read the first line of each file (I checked printing them), but the `if` statements don't work.

```
for file in os.listdir(".."):
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            with open(os.path.join('..\\',file)) as tempfile:
                if tempfile.readline().strip() == '//Q':
                    QFile = os.path.join('..\\',file)
                if tempfile.readline().strip() == '//H':
                    HFile = os.path.join('..\\',file)
```

I'm not sure if that's the correct way to save the path afterwards, but the issue is on the `if`d, since `print` statements (not included here) inside either them are never triggered, even though the files are being read correctly. Printing their `readline.strip()` values, displays the flags as expected.

Right now the test files are simple .txt with `//Q` or `//H` on the fist line and a bunch of stuff that will be sorted and stored afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your problem is in reading the first *two* lines of the file: your `//H` comparison advances the file descriptor.  Also, you assume that the flag is the entire line.  Instead ...

```
with open(os.path.join('..\\',file)) as tempfile:
    first_line = tempfile.readline().strip()
    if '//Q' in first_line:
        QFile = os.path.join('..\\',file)
    elif '//H' in first_line:
        HFile = os.path.join('..\\',file)
```

Does that handle you needs?

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you! So every use of .readline() is reading a different line then? can't belive it was so simple. 

Thanks again, have a great week

Comment: Yes; the `readline` documentation tells you that.  It's a hungry method that eats input.